# Getting topmost search result per group from Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using full text search capability of Neo4j to get nearest matching skills against an input list of search strings. Below in the cypher query.

```
UNWIND ["nursing care requirements", "relatives tutoring student nurses", "blood pressures", "emotional support", "intravenous infusions", "junior staff", "patient samples", "pulses", "workloads"] AS x
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("full-text-skills", x) YIELD node, score
RETURN x, node.name, score
```

It runs fine and return all the matching result (1000 rows for the above example). Now I want to fetch the top most matching skill in terms of the `score` property returned by `db.index.fulltext.queryNodes` (1 row per input item in the list). I tried adding limit after the `return` statement but it put limit on the whole output. What I really want is to put a limit of search results per item in the input list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution to the above problem. We can use collect to gather results per group and depending on the limit we can get the results per group. Cypher query will be -

```
UNWIND ["nursing care requirements", "relatives tutoring student nurses", "blood pressures", "emotional support", "intravenous infusions", "junior staff", "patient samples", "pulses", "workloads"] AS x
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("full-text-skills", x) YIELD node, score
RETURN x,collect(node.name)[0..3]
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a knowledge base article on [limiting MATCH results per row](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/) that should help you out, and does include the approach you found for getting a slice of the collected results.